# Why "an output column name has to stand alone, that is, it cannot be used in an expression" in ORDER BY?

Tags: postgresql

In the document of PostgreSQL

> The  ORDER BY  clause specifies the sort order:
>
> ```
> SELECT select_list
>     FROM table_expression
>     ORDER BY sort_expression1 [ASC | DESC] [NULLS { FIRST | LAST }]
>              [, sort_expression2 [ASC | DESC] [NULLS { FIRST |
>  LAST }] ...]
> ```
>
> The sort expression(s) can be any expression that would be valid in
>   the query's select list. An example is:
>
> ```
> SELECT a, b FROM table1 ORDER BY a + b, c;
> ```
>
> ...
>
> A  sort_expression  can also be the column label or number of an
>   output column, as in:
>
> ```
> SELECT a + b AS sum, c FROM table1 ORDER BY sum;
> SELECT a, max(b) FROM table1 GROUP BY a ORDER BY 1;
> ```
>
> both of which sort by the first output column. Note that **an output
>   column name has to stand alone, that is, it cannot be used in an
>   expression** — for example, this is not correct:
>
> ```
> SELECT a + b AS sum, c FROM table1 ORDER BY sum + c;          -- wrong
> ```
>
> This restriction is made to reduce ambiguity. There is still ambiguity
>   if an  ORDER BY  item is a simple name that could match either an
>   output column name or a column from the table expression. The output
>   column is used in such cases. This would only cause confusion if you
>   use  AS  to rename an output column to match some other table column's
>   name.

Can someone explain what "an output column name has to stand alone, that is, it cannot be used in an expression" means?

Why is `ORDER BY a+b` in the first example  correct, while `ORDER BY sum+c` in the last example wrong?

What ambiguity can the last example provide?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an ambiguity if `table1` has a column named `sum`. Without the rule, the parser would have to consider for each name whether it is a column name or an expression alias. With the rule, it only has to consider that if the name stands alone. So the rule reduces ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks. What does "expression" means in  "it cannot be used in an expression"?

Comment: An expression is something like `f(a) - CASE WHEN b = 'x' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`. Something you can have in the `SELECT` or `ORDER BY` list.

Comment: In "an output column name has to stand alone, that is, it cannot be used in an expression", how do "an output column name has to stand alone" and "it cannot be used in an expression" mean the same as implied by "that is"?

Comment: I'd say that "stand alone" is for readers that don't have a clear concept of what an "SQL expression" is. If I say `ORDER BY sum`, `sum` "stands alone", i.e., the expression consists only of a single variable name. In `ORDER BY sum + 42`, `sum` does *not* "stand alone", i.e., it is part of a more complicated expression. In a way, it is similar to `ORDER BY 1` vs. `ORDER BY x+1`. The first is interpreted as "order by the first element of the `SELECT` list", whereas the second expression means "order by the sum of `x` and 1". Instead of 1, you can use an alias, but with the same restrictions.

Comment: Thanks. Why is `ORDER BY a+b` in the first example correct, given that `a` and `b ` are not standalone in it?

Comment: Because they are column names and no aliases.